# "useradd: invalid user name" in Ansible user module

Tags: ansible

My Ansible playbook:

```
- hosts: docker
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
  - include_vars: users.yml
  - name: Add users to local docker groups 
    user: name='{{users}}' groups='{{group_name}}' append=yes
```

`users.yml` file:

```
users: 
    - jjohnson

group_name: docker
```

`ansible-playbook docker-groups.yml`:

```
PLAY [docker] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server]

TASK [include_vars] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server]

TASK [Add users to local docker groups] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "useradd: invalid user name '['jjohnson']'\n", "name": "['jjohnson']", "rc": 3}
```

Why is it falling?

Comment: How come it is an unclear question? OP uses wrong data structure and it is a debugging question. OP clearly states the problem, shows MVCE and the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `users` variable as a list (then Ansible internally passes this value as a JSON representation to the `useradd` executable which fails).

You should define the value as a string:

```
users: jjohnson
```

---

But if you wanted to add multiple users (as the plural name `users` suggests), you should use loops.  There is an example right for you at [the top of the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops).

Comment: i wanted to have a yml file with a list of users, so users are not listed in the actual playbook

Comment: Nothing stops you from doing that. I have answered your question.

Comment: Thanks, I got it! Sorry, coming from chef, it's a bit different, for instance for user module, it does useradd if the user is not on the node, and it does a usermod if the user is